# Get Data from database to ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

Short one.

A database named ComDet , and column cID(PK) , cName , cDet , mainCate(FK) , Subcat(FK).

this suppose to get the data from table ComDet to the combobox..

```
DataSet ds2;

private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
    conn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter daSearch = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT cName FROM ComDet", conn);
    ds2 = new DataSet();
    daSearch.Fill(ds2, "daSearch");
    ListU.ValueMember = "cName";
    ListU.DataSource = ds2.Tables["ComDet"];
    ListU.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    ListU.Enabled = true;
}
```

but it didnt work.. where did i go wrong?
The Data(cName) from database table ComDet is not shown in the combobox. –

Comment: You have failed to tell us what "it didn't work" means!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The Data(cName) from database table ComDet is not shown in the combobox.

Comment: Is it in the DataTable? Have you set a breakpoint with the debugger to see what data are returned?

Comment: Ah.. How do i do that? I am fairly new to C#.

Comment: This should be the first thing that students are taught: "[Debugging in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx)".

Comment: oh wait.. u said something about datatable.. and i change it to
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

            ListU.DataSource = dt1;

            daSearch.Fill(dt1);

and now it worked!.. thx for the tips.. :)

Comment: Sql Objects in C# make use of unmanaged resources. Use `using` statements: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** You are assigning database table name `ComDet` as `DataSource` but not `DataTable` Name `daSearch` to `ComboBox`.

**Solution :** you need to assign valid `DataTable` Name to `ComboBox` as  `Datasource`.

Replace This :

```
ListU.DataSource = ds2.Tables["ComDet"];
```

With This:

```
ListU.DataSource = ds2.Tables["daSearch"];
```

(or)

```
ListU.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0];
```

**Complete Code:**

```
DataSet ds2;

private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
conn.Open();

SqlDataAdapter daSearch = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT cName FROM ComDet", conn);
ds2 = new DataSet();
daSearch.Fill(ds2, "daSearch");
ListU.ValueMember = "cName";
ListU.DataSource = ds2.Tables["daSearch"];
ListU.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
ListU.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin: you need to provide `DataTable` name `daSearch` to `DataSource`, see my edited answer, it works perfectly

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin: You are welcome :) , I'm glad to be help of you.

Comment: So what do i do if i wanted whatever i chose from the combobox.. to show everything that it have in the database table.. such as , if i choose a company name from the combo box , the button then sends all the data of the company name chosen to a datagridview..

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin: you can get `SelectedItem` property of the Combobox to get selected company name and fire a SQL Select query -> `select * from table where companayname=ListU.SelectedItem.ToString()`...

Comment: Additional information: The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRowView" could not be bound.

Comment: i changed to ListU.SelectedValue.ToString() , and it says "invalid column name"

Answer (score 1):

So the question asks how to get data from **database to combobox**. Personally, I find using the `DataSet` class to be unpreferable - it is quite prone to errors like the asker is experiencing here.

Try this approach. Which reads all the `cName` into a `List` and binds the `List` to the `ComboBox`. Simple and readable code. The use of `using` statements also ensures that the unmanaged resources are released efficiently.

```
private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = 
            "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT cName FROM ComDet", conn))
        {
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["cName"]));
                }
            }
        }
   }
   ListU.DataSource = new BindingSource(list, null);
   ListU.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
   ListU.Enabled = true;
}
```